# How to aggregate into a map

Tags: mongodb

How to convert the result to map after the aggregated $group

After $group get the following data

```
{
    "_id" : "red",
    "count" : 5
},
{
    "_id" : "blue",
    "count" : 8
}
```

how to convert to:

```
{
    "red":5,
    "blue":8
}
```

Comment: i dont think it possible,Mongo is a collection based database where you can get a list of documents not as Map result please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/

Comment: Basically the last two stages from that example with `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } } } }, { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" } } }` added as the last two stages to your pipeline.

Comment: If you don't have a version supporting `$replaceRoot` or `$arrayToObject` then you don't really need them as a `.reduce((o,{ _id, count}) => ({ ...o, [_id]: count }), {})` on the array result of your existing pipeline will produce exactly the same result. Sometimes it's just better to do this sort of thing in code than asking a database to do that manipulation.

Comment: Successfully run, thank you